# Can a lower semi-continuous function blow up to $+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I was confused in lecture today that the professor said a l.s.c function can not blow up to $+\infty$...

In my point of view, a l.s.c function can blow up to $+\infty$... for example, we take $f(x)=1/|x|$. Clearly we have $f(0)=\infty$ at $0$ and I think $f(x)$ is l.s.c since for any $x_n\to 0$, $\liminf f(x_n)=\infty=f(0)$...

In high dimension case, we can construct a similar example...

Am I right? Or I miss sth trivial here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A lower semicontinuous and convex functions that is $-\infty$ for some $x$ is nowhere finite. Or in other words, if it is finite for some $x_0$ then it is never $-\infty$. Check also proper convex functions.

The indicator function of a closed and convex set is the prime example of a  lower-semicontinuous mapping that takes the value $+\infty$ somewhere. (Even in infinite-dimensional spaces)

Maybe somebody mixed up the things?

Comment: I wondered too. I was trying to suggest a l.s.c function from $\mathbb R^N\to (0,+\infty]$ which blows up at a finite $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ measures layers...But I was told by professor that there never will be one if it is l.s.c.... Probably there are some misunderstanding between us...

Comment: btw, why you point out convexity? I don't need my function to be convex.

Comment: Convex *and* lower-semicontinuous functions have the nice property that the function value $-\infty$ can only occur in pathological cases, namely only when the function is everywhere $\pm\infty$. The statement of your teacher reminded me sounded similar to this fact.